# Copy dynamic range from worksheets in target workbook, and paste to new workbook in separate sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I tried altering some code I have which copied all worksheets and pasted them into a new workbook into a new sheet.

Problem is I only want specific areas which all start at A5 but the last row and column is dynamic, and constantly changing.

Ideally I would like to copy each range into a new sheet in the batch rater, and keep the source sheet name only difference being I want to copy the range into A1 of the new sheets.

```
  Sub CopyWorkbook()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, sb As Workbook
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim curName As String
    Dim copy_value As Range

    ' get reference to both workbooks
    Set sb = Workbooks("Current VA Rating Structure_test")
    Set wb = Workbooks("rater_tables")

    ' loop through worksheets in "Rating Structure" workbook
    For Each sh In sb.Worksheets

        ' get the max row & col of the worksheet, as well as its name
        lRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lCol = sh.Cells(lRow, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
        curName = sh.Name

        ' add a worksheet to the "Rate Tables" workbook and set its name
        wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(1)).Name = curName

        ' copy the range from the old sheet to the new one
        sh.Range(sh.Cells(5, 1), sh.Cells(lRow, lCol)).Copy wb.Worksheets(curName).Range("A1")
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range.Copy` doesn't have an `After` parameter, but a `Destination` parameter. That said, you need to create the sheet in the rater_tables wb and then paste there.

Comment: So I would have to create 52 sheets first, and then set it to paste the values in A1?

Comment: No, you could add the sheet as a step inside the loop.

Comment: Got it BigBen, for some reason I am not having issue with the actual content being copied. copy_value = sh.Range(sh.Cells(5, 1), sh.Cells(lRow, lCol)).Value is only storing a single cell, and not the whole range.

Comment: I think your problem is actually that you only do a value transfer into one cell: `wb.Worksheets(curName).Range("A1").Value = copy_value`. You'll need to use `Resize` to transfer the entire range.

Comment: I made some more edits, and now encountered a new problem, its only copying the first column of the data instead of the range of the data. Even when I added resize(lrow,lcol) to wb.Worksheets(curName).Range("A1"). What are your thoughts Bigben?

Comment: Figured it out BigBen, appreciate the help. I attached the working code.